# Spring Boot 2.0 application running but unable to access it on port 8080 on Windows machine

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot project that has been developed on a Mac and runs fine. I'm in the process of moving the application to a machine within a manufacturing plan that has no internet access and strict security policies in place.

We've installed IntelliJ and Java10, copied across the project and tried to run it within IntelliJ. While the console output confirms that the application is running;

"Started VisualisationApplication in 3.875 seconds (JVM running for 5.053)"

There is only one error that appears in the console and I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the problem;

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehause.groovy.reflection.CachedClass

I've tried to set Spring Boot to use port 80 by adding spring.port=80 to my application.configuration file, but that doesn't work, and I also see no confirmation from Spring upon application startup to confirm that the application is running on that port (I'm sure I used to see it in the past).

UPDATE:

I've downgraded the application within IntelliJ to use Java 8, apparently the Groovy package uses a lot of reflection and Java 9+ is more strict. The error has now gone, but the same issue appears.

Once thing I did notice, yesterday when I first tried to run the application, the computer said it needed extra privileges for certain features of Java and IntelliJ, I clicked cancel as I didn't have anyone with me that had admin credentials. Would this cause a problem, maybe not allowing Java access to the network? We've since given the user admin access but it didn't resolve the problem.

UPDATE 2

It looks like Spring isn't initialising Tomcat.

Comment: Can you please show start logs??

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this one

```
# HTTP Server
server:
  port: 8080   # HTTP (Tomcat) port
```

in your application.yaml file

Comment: I'm not using yml, I'm using the application.properties file. I've already tried server.port=80 and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the cause of the problem, but I suspect that for some reason Spring wasn't seeing Tomcat on the class path, even though it existed, so there was probably an issue with the way I had defined the external libraries which I had to do manually as Maven couldn't download the sources with the computer not having internet access.

In the end the I.T. department allowed the machine to connect to the internet to allow Maven to handle the dependencies, virus scan the machine and put it back on the production line. This resolved the problem and Tomcat is now being initialised.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow below steps; if they don't work then please show server start logs

1. add `server.port=0` in your `application.properties`; if Tomcat starts then it means it has picked any random port so issue might be you have installed Apache/IIS on same machine as ISS/Apache use default port 80.
2. If you want your application to run on port 80 then use `server.port = 8080` or something which work and make settings in Apache if you are using to forward your port to 80.